# javascript asynchronous error handling - suggested approaches

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, error-handling, try-catch

Im researching some information on error handling within our javascript application. Now, the conventional & suggested approach is to build logs & use 'Try / Catch' to deal with errors, however, in our code, a large amount of code is Async & the lead developer is of the view that we should steer towards 'window.onerror' approach.

I understand this is a bit generic in nature but I am interested in hearing the Js community's view of forsaking async error handling to 'window.onerror'. We are consciously focused on performance within our app so that is major influence in our decisions.

Thanks,

Comment: [Promises!](http://spion.github.io/posts/why-i-am-switching-to-promises.html)

Comment: Thanks @Bergi, I think Promises are ringing the sound of inevitability, our concern is the amount of work required to convert & performance remains a core concern.

Comment: But code will become much easier to read and work with, and promises are quite performant as well.

Comment: @Bergi, yes you are right. I did a bit of reading & some frameworks appear to be catching up to callbacks. Positive news & thanks